# How to control page breaks with react-native-html-to-pdf?

Tags: react-native, html-to-pdf

I am generating a pdf document using [react-native-html-to-pdf](https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf).

When the document contains a long list of elements it is possible for some elements to span two pages within the same document.

For example this simple html:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <section style="border:solid 1px black;"><p>item</p></section>
    <!-- sections repeat 32 times omitted for brevity -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I get a document that looks like this at the page break:

[image: pdf with section spanning two pages]

How can I control this?  Does it depend on the html elements in the document?